# Regular expression to find a match for repeated pattern

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I am trying to write a reg expression to find match of 5 different character repeated 3-5 times.
e.g:
   I have 4 nos and 1 char like 1,2,3,4,a.
and i just want to check whether one of these digit/char is present in a string in repeated pattern for 3-5 times. like "22299" should return true because "222" is present here for 3 times.
if string is like this "22300" it should return false because "223" is not a pattern.If it was
like this "22333" then should return true.

i tried [1234a]{3,5} but its returning true for "22300" pattern and also tried this (1|2|3|4|a){3,5} but same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this expression:

```
([1234a])\1{2,4}
```

Comment: :If i want a char to act as a wildcard say "c" when it comes with any char or no.
e.g "22c99" now c will act like no 2,so test will return true.
and if it's like this "229c0" then will return false.